# Is A* with an admissible but inconsistent heuristic optimal?

Tags: search, heuristics, a-star, admissible-heuristic, consistent-heuristic

I understand that, in tree search, an admissible heuristic implies that $A*$ is optimal. The intuitive way I think about this is as follows:

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two costs from any respective nodes $p$ and $q$ to the goal. Assume $P<Q$. Let $P'$ be an estimation of $P$. $P'\le P \Rightarrow P'<Q$. It follows from uniform-cost-search that the path through $p$ must be explored.

What I don't understand, is why the idea of an admissible heuristic does not apply as well to "graph-search". If a heuristic is admissible but inconsistent, would that imply that $A*$ is not optimal? Could you please provide an example of an admissible heuristic that results in a non-optimal solution?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by optimal.

1. A* will always find the optimal solution (that is, the algorithm is *admissible*) as long as the heuristic is admissible. (Note that the definition of admissible is overloaded and means something slightly different for an algorithm and a heuristic.)
2. If you talk about the *set* of nodes expanded by A*, then it expands the minimal *set* of nodes up to tie-breaking even with an inconsistent heuristic.
3. If you talk about the number of *expansions*, then A* is not optimal. A* can perform up to $2^N$ expansions of $N$ states with an inconsistent heuristic. This result comes from [Martelli, 1977](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0004370277900029).
4. Algorithm B has worst-case $N^2$ expansions and [budgeted graph search (BGS)](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Enathanst/papers/IBEX.pdf) has worst-case $N \log C$, where $C$ is the optimal solution cost.

You can see a demo that shows the worst-case performance of A* as well as the performance of BGS here:

https://www.movingai.com/SAS/INC/